# vc++ 2015 The use of RichTextBox

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

How can I output some value from MyForm.cpp file to MyForm.h richtextbox?

In my MyForm.h

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->richTextBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this->richTextBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 13);
            this->richTextBox1->Name = L"richTextBox1";
            this->richTextBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(259, 237);
            this->richTextBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->richTextBox1->Text = L"";
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 12);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    public: void insertText(std::string msg) {          
            this->richTextBox1->Text = gcnew String(msg.c_str());
            this->richTextBox1->SelectionColor = Color::Red;
        }
    };
```

In my MyForm.cpp

```
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Test1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);

    form.insertText("123"); 
}
```

The get no error during compile but it output nothing to the richtextbox. Is there any method to do that? Some of my code must be run in cpp file.

Comment: `Application::Run` won't return until you close the form. Put your code in the constructor or in `OnLoad`

Comment: Can you make an example to put the code in the constructor or in OnLoad, I am sorry about that I am new for c++ programming

Comment: You're expected to have a minimal understanding of what you're trying to do on this site,  it's not for tutoring about the basics of the language. BTW that's not C++, it's C++/CLI, and it's *not* a language for beginners, it's a niche language for a specific task.